# Ball to Ball Collision resolution

Tags: graphics, language-agnostic, collision-detection, game-physics

I was going through some collision detection tutorials on youtube, In one of the tutorial, the guy used the following code to resolve a collision between two balls:

```
/**
 * Rotates coordinate system for velocities
 *
 * Takes velocities and alters them as if the coordinate system they're on was rotated
 *
 * @param  Object | velocity | The velocity of an individual particle
 * @param  Float  | angle    | The angle of collision between two objects in radians
 * @return Object | The altered x and y velocities after the coordinate system has been rotated
 */

function rotate(velocity, angle) {
    const rotatedVelocities = {
        x: velocity.x * Math.cos(angle) - velocity.y * Math.sin(angle),
        y: velocity.x * Math.sin(angle) + velocity.y * Math.cos(angle)
    };

    return rotatedVelocities;
}

/**
 * Swaps out two colliding particles' x and y velocities after running through
 * an elastic collision reaction equation
 *
 * @param  Object | particle      | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @param  Object | otherParticle | A particle object with x and y coordinates, plus velocity
 * @return Null | Does not return a value
 */

function resolveCollision(particle, otherParticle) {
    const xVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.x - otherParticle.velocity.x;
    const yVelocityDiff = particle.velocity.y - otherParticle.velocity.y;

    const xDist = otherParticle.x - particle.x;
    const yDist = otherParticle.y - particle.y;

    // Prevent accidental overlap of particles
    if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0) {

        // Grab angle between the two colliding particles
        const angle = -Math.atan2(otherParticle.y - particle.y, otherParticle.x - particle.x);

        // Store mass in var for better readability in collision equation
        const m1 = particle.mass;
        const m2 = otherParticle.mass;

        // Velocity before equation
        const u1 = rotate(particle.velocity, angle);
        const u2 = rotate(otherParticle.velocity, angle);

        // Velocity after 1d collision equation
        const v1 = { x: u1.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u2.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u1.y };
        const v2 = { x: u2.x * (m1 - m2) / (m1 + m2) + u1.x * 2 * m2 / (m1 + m2), y: u2.y };

        // Final velocity after rotating axis back to original location
        const vFinal1 = rotate(v1, -angle);
        const vFinal2 = rotate(v2, -angle);

        // Swap particle velocities for realistic bounce effect
        particle.velocity.x = vFinal1.x;
        particle.velocity.y = vFinal1.y;

        otherParticle.velocity.x = vFinal2.x;
        otherParticle.velocity.y = vFinal2.y;
    }
}
```

I've mostly understood this code. However, I'm unable to understand how this if condition is working to find out whether the balls have overlapped or not.

```
if (xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0)
```

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: @GuyCoder I've verified it with 1000 balls moving with a random velocity in a space and colliding together.  Can you explain why `(xVelocityDiff * xDist >=0)` and `(yVelocityDiff * yDist >= 0)` would make sense?

Comment: When I see problems with different dimensions, in this case horizontal and vertical, or X and Y, and they mix them in an expression without a comment, it draws my attention. After years of coding, certain patterns jump out at you and some of those patterns are for looking for bugs. This matched a pattern to check for bugs. As I noted I didn't say it was a bug, and that it should also document what it was doing. As soon as I saw `dot product` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53499886/1243762) and having taken physics that was all I needed to know it was correct.

Comment: To put my previous comment more in context with programming, think of different dimensions as different types, even though you could think of them as both having the type length or location, I think of them as an even more specific type. One problem I dislike with many languages is that they let you use the basic types without   redefining them. In C using an int type as pointer is a classic case. When I started to learn ADA one of the oddest things at first was that you could NOT just use the int type, you had to create a new type from int and then use that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking the differences of positions and velocities, you view everything in the frame of `otherParticle`. In that frame, `otherParticle` is standing still at the origin and `particle` is moving with `velocityDiff`. Here is how it looks like:

[image: Visualization]

The term `xVelocityDiff * xDist + yVelocityDiff * yDist` is the dot product of the two vectors. This dot product is negative if `velocityDiff` points somewhat in the opposite direction of `dist`, i.e. if the particle is getting closer like in the above image. If the dot product is positive, the particle is moving away from `otherParticle` and you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Ah totally missed seeing that it was a dot product. Thanks.

Comment: @NicoSchertler - The `resolveCollision` function is invoked when a collision has already been detected, so it's still not clear to me why we further need to check for the dot product to prevent overlapping. One-dimensional collision is also calculated if the dot product is positive, but you mention that nothing has to be done in this case, may you please clarify both points? thanks.

Comment: @MrShabana It is mostly used to preserve consistency with discrete-time step simulations. If the dot product is negative, the collision will resolve itself as it was most likely only a very slight touching or one of the velocities has already been modified by a different collision resolution. Or the resolution already changed the velocity but the collision still exists in the next time step. To be absolutely correct, one would turn back the time to the point when the collision actually happened and resolve from there.